# QGIS: Coloring a map relative to the values of certain attributes

Tags: qgis, expression

I'd like to color the map using the "select by expression". I tried to use color_rgba(255, 0, 0, 255) for example. It only changes the color to be completely yellow which is the "selection color" in the general settings and project settings. So do I have to disable the selection color in the general settings somehow, or is there another way to use the color from the expression?

Edit:
I basically want to color a map relative to the values of certain attributes.
To give an example, I want to be able to color streets relative to their length with an expression which probably looks like the following:
color_rgba(255, 0, 0, (length / max_length) * 255).
Where would I specify such a coloring option?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the selection color in the project properties tab but I suspect that isn't what you want.

If you just want to color in a selection of your data (possibly so you can add a second color to other values later) then you need to go to the styling tab of the layer properties (double click the layer or right click and select `properties`).

Then change single symbol to Rule-based:
[image]

double click on the rule and enter your filter in the filter box (click the `...` button to open the expression editor).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I think that could solve the problem but if I enter my rule / filter (color_rgba(255, 0, 0, 255)) and apply it, the map is completely gone.

Comment: You need an expression that evaluates to true for the features you want to colour. You set the colour further down the tab.

Comment: I want  to colorize the map of a city regarding the value of certain attributes, e.g. color_rgba(255, 0, 0, (income_mean/max_income)*255).